# How to send customGET with several ids and other parameter with Restangular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I want to send several ids with other parameter from `customGET` method. It's my method but doesn't work:

```
var selection = [2,10,20];

// send GET /api/user/export/file?param1=test&ids=2,10,20
Restangular.all('user').customGET('export/file',{param1:'test',ids:selection}).then(function(response) {
/*  */
        })
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem with `'ids[]':`to send array:

```
Restangular.all('user').customGET('export/file',{param1:'test','ids[]':selection}).then(function(response) {
/*  */
        })
```